# Memory mapping for static variables

Tags: c, memory-management, static

Source:

```
func_1()
{
    static int i = 10;
    printf("%s : %d\n", __func__, i);
}

func_2()
{
    static int i = 20;
    printf("%s : %d\n", __func__, i);
}

main() {
    static int i = 30;
    func_1();
    func_2();
    printf("%s : %d\n", __func__, i);
}
```

Output:

```
func_1 : 10
func_2 : 20
main : 30
```

How compiler differentiate variables in data segment with respect to functions?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how the compiler knows what scope it's in?

Comment: *How* the compiler handles it is not specified, it's up to the compiler. As long as it behaves as specified, does it really matter?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes. also, how the actual value is fetched.

Comment: Just like it does it with **global** static variables that share **identical** names, but are located in **different** source files. It simply prepends each variable with a unique prefix, before it goes over the code and translates them into memory addresses. It's just another phase in the process of compilation.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg ok.. handling is up to the compiler. but, how the data segment is managed for data fetching? Does it up to the compiler too?

Comment: In fact, there might even be a simpler way for the compiler to do that. Just compile the functions one by one. Whenever you encounter a local static variable declaration, allocate another entry in the data section, and replace every reference of that variable in the current function, with the address of the new entry.

Comment: @user3832066 The C specification doesn't mention things like "data segment", "bss" or anything like that. It's all up to the compiler/linker/platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `i` is just local to the scope of each of the functions, while each such variable is stored in its own area. The compiler generates code so that each of them is loaded from a distinct memory address.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more than one way for the compiler to handle this, but here is one option:

- Compile the functions one by one
- Whenever you encounter a static variable declaration, allocate a new entry in the data section
- Whenever you encounter a static variable reference, replace it with the address of the new entry

If you think about it, this method can also be applied for non-static local variables (using the stack instead).

Of course, with non-static local variables, the full translation of the address will only occur during runtime.

But the concept is the same - once the function is compiled, the names of its variables are meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely related to the scope of the variable. Here, three `i` s are three separate variables, each having their own scope, in that particular function which it is defined.

`func_1 : 10` is correct, because, `i` is local to `func_1()` here.

```
func_1()
{
    static int i = 10;
    printf("%s : %d\n", __func__, i);
}
```

`func_2 : 20` is also correct because, `i` is local to `func_2()` here.

```
func_2()
{
    static int i = 20;
    printf("%s : %d\n", __func__, i);
}
```

`main : 30` is also correct because, `i` is local to `main()` there.

Side Note:

1. If you're thinking because of `static` modifier, all the variables will be tread as a single one, then won't you have run into *multiple definition* error? :-)
2. In the case of a `local` and a `global` variable having the same name, the `local` variable will be given preference by the function.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the static variable is local to the block within which it is defined but it retains the value between function calls. In your case there are 3 instances of the variable `i` and they are distinct from one another. Each of them are stored in separate memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

As @Blagovest Buyukliev mentioned each `i` in each function is different and is only within that function. After compilation code does not know about variable names but rather just refers as appropriate locations/memory address.

So if you change your code slightly to print address of `i` as well you will see that each `i` has different address.

```
func_1()
{
    static int i = 10;
    printf("%s : %d, %p\n", __func__, i, &i);
}

func_2()
{
    static int i = 20;
    printf("%s : %d, %p\n", __func__, i, &i);
}

main() {
    static int i = 30;
    func_1();
    func_2();
    printf("%s : %d, %p\n", __func__, i, &i);
}
```

Sample output

```
func_1 : 10, 0x601028
func_2 : 20, 0x601024
main : 30, 0x601020
```